# Changing the alpha value of individual points in a matplotlib contourf plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to implement domain coloring using `matplotlib.pyplot.contourf`. I have everything figured out except for how to change the alpha of the individual z values. After extensive docs research I still couldn't find the answer. Can this be done or should I use another method?

Comment: Can you show us relevant code?

Comment: what do you mean by 'change the alpha of individual z values'? Do you mean change the alpha at a given point on the mesh, or change the alpha of a given colour throughout the mesh?

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37168017/domain-coloring-in-python) page for a hopefully better worded question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce custom variation in alpha values based on z if you use a custom colormap. This http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html is the official example, with LinearSegmentedColormap.

Comment: I have tried this method. The only problem is that I want to use other values to change the alpha instead of the plotted values. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37168017/domain-coloring-in-python) page for a better formulated question.